# horizontally Aligning three divs not working with only html

Tags: html

I have some code, and my `stylesheet.css` is not working so I figured out can't have css. I can only include html. I have 3 `divs` and I need to put them in a horizontal align. How do I do this?

Here is my code.

```
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
```

And my css which isn't working.

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I need to horizontally align these  3 divs only with html.

Comment: Why CSS is not working?. May be with your code we can help

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: I suspect the path to your stylesheet is wrong. Though you can use `<style></style>` Tags for now.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't using the style tags. That caused the problem, but I can also use tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly easy problem to solve, and the `table` tag should help. The `table` tag does not use css.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Div 1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Div 2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>Div 3</div>
      </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```